# Missing Dependencies Spyder3 Python 3.5 - pylint 0.25 / rope 0.9.4

Tags: debian, apt, python, spyder

I have some problems with missing dependencies when starting Spyder 3 with Python 3.5. I use Debian Strech and switched to Python 3.5 as standard setting It says when starting Spyder3 rope 0.9.4 and pylint 0.2.5 is NOK.

Here is the list from Spyder3:

```
jedi >=0.9.0     :  0.10.0 (OK)
matplotlib >=1.0 :  2.0.0 (OK)
nbconvert >=4.0  :  4.2.0 (OK)
numpy >=1.7      :  1.12.1 (OK)
pandas >=0.13.1  :  0.19.2 (OK)
pep8 >=0.6       :  1.7.0 (OK)
psutil >=0.3     :  5.0.1 (OK)
pyflakes >=0.6.0 :  1.3.0 (OK)
pygments >=2.0   :  2.2.0 (OK)
pylint >=0.25    :  None (OK)
qtconsole >=4.2.0:  4.2.1 (OK)
rope >=0.9.4     :  None (NOK)
sphinx >=0.6.6   :  1.4.9 (OK)
sympy >=0.7.3    :  None (NOK)
```

I tried to install pylint3 and got:

```
apt-get install pylint3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  [deleted huge list packages for autoremoval]
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-astroid python3-isort python3-lazy-object-proxy python3-wrapt
Suggested packages:
  pylint-doc python3-mccabe
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pylint3 python3-astroid python3-isort python3-lazy-object-proxy
  python3-wrapt
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 384 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,861 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 amd64 python3-lazy-object-proxy amd64 1.2.2-1 [20.7 kB]
Get:2 amd64 python3-wrapt amd64 1.9.0-2 [31.5 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 python3-astroid all 1.4.9-1 [89.7 kB]
Get:4 http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 python3-isort all 4.2.5+ds1-2 [38.0 kB]
Get:5 amd64 pylint3 all 1.6.5-1 [204 kB]
Fetched 384 kB in 0s (430 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package python3-lazy-object-proxy.
(Reading database ... 298576 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-lazy-object-proxy_1.2.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-lazy-object-proxy (1.2.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-wrapt.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-wrapt_1.9.0-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3-wrapt (1.9.0-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-astroid.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-astroid_1.4.9-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-astroid (1.4.9-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-isort.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-isort_4.2.5+ds1-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-isort (4.2.5+ds1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package pylint3.
Preparing to unpack .../pylint3_1.6.5-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking pylint3 (1.6.5-1) ...
Setting up pylint (1.6.5-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package pylint (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python3-lazy-object-proxy (1.2.2-1) ...
Setting up python3-isort (4.2.5+ds1-2) ...
Setting up python3-wrapt (1.9.0-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-spyder:
 python3-spyder depends on pylint; however:
  Package pylint is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-spyder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.6.1-2) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-spyder:
 python-spyder depends on pylint; however:
  Package pylint is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-spyder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python3-astroid (1.4.9-1) ...
Setting up pylint3 (1.6.5-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of spyder:
 spyder depends on python-spyder (= 3.1.3+dfsg1-3); however:
  Package python-spyder is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package spyder (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of spyder3:
 spyder3 depends on python3-spyder (= 3.1.3+dfsg1-3); however:
  Package python3-spyder is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package spyder3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 pylint
 python3-spyder
 python-spyder
 spyder
 spyder3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: which spyder package did you install?  spyder or spyder3?  the `spyder` package in debian is for python 2.7, while `spyder3` is for python 3.x

Comment: Where was something wrong with apt before you try to install ` pylint3`  you wrote `0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.`  As root  `dpkg --configure -a && apt -f install` or with sudo `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install`

Comment: I have Python 3.x and Spyder 3.x (I switched from the default package in debian, Python 2.7 to 3.x). Yes, I tried to reinstall spyder3 and first I used apt-get remove spyder3, some error messages appeared. Now, I just started spyder 3 again and only one missing dependcy accured, namely rope3.

Answer (score 1):

I had missing dependencies for pylint and rope.  I wasn't able to update or upgrade via apt-get to resolve missing deps.

Running:
$ sudo pip install -U spyder

Resolved the missing dependencies.